# insert values on trigger in temporal tables in postgres

Tags: postgresql, temporal-database

So I am new to using procedures and triggers and it is really confusing me
I have used `temporal tables` and want to basically create a history table of records inserted,updated or deleted.

Infact I have created my history table and works fine when I use this trigger sql

```
DROP TRIGGER if exists versioning_trigger on mytable;
CREATE TRIGGER versioning_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON mytable FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE versioning('sys_period', 'table_history', true);
```

This creates records of the rows updated or deleted,precisely copies the old row record from `mytable` into `table_history` table and updates the record in `mytable`.But I want to insert the updated record from `mytable` to `table_history` also so that it has records of all types('current active record'and 'record before updation').Also insert some other fields in `table_history` when the trigger is executed.

I want to ask

1. How is it possible to have different trigger events(BEFORE or AFTER) together in one `CREATE TRIGGER` query in temporal_tables?
2. Is it possible to insert new field values in `table_history` on trigger execution? How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

> A trigger procedure is created with the CREATE FUNCTION command,
>   declaring it as a function with no arguments and a return type of
>   trigger

and also

1. same trigger can't fire both before and after event - just create two triggers if you really need it

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html

> Determines whether the function is called before, after, or instead of
>   the event.

2. use `NEW` instead of `OLD` for new values

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

> `NEW`
>
> Data type RECORD; variable holding the new database row for
>   INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is
>   unassigned in statement-level triggers and for DELETE operations.